# Android Studio crashing on launch

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, android-studio

Alright, a short insight, I recently set up my new Lenovo y50 to dual boot Arch with Windows 8.1. I use Arch linux as my dev environment. I can launch Android Studio 5.6 and then it updates to 6.1. After the update (this happened both on 6.0 and 6.1) it barely starts to load my project and the it kills my laptop. No error screen or reporting, just powers off instantly. I have looked through the logs and I am afraid I just am not familiar enough with kernel operations to understand these errors. The following output is from the command `journalctl --since=today`:

```
    Jun 19 21:51:04 Archer /etc/gdm/Xsession[6315]: Window manager warning: Log level 16: STACK_OP_RAISE_ABOVE: sibling window 0x2000d07 not in stack
    Jun 19 21:55:43 Archer /etc/gdm/Xsession[6315]: [1352606]   WARN - api.vfs.impl.local.FileWatcher - Watcher terminated with exit code 0
    Jun 19 21:55:43 Archer /etc/gdm/Xsession[6315]: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=350m; support was removed in 8.0
    Jun 19 21:55:55 Archer /etc/gdm/Xsession[6315]: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=350m; support was removed in 8.0
    Jun 19 21:55:57 Archer /etc/gdm/Xsession[6315]: Window manager warning: Invalid WM_TRANSIENT_FOR window 0x2000024 specified for 0x200002b ( ).
    Jun 19 21:56:07 Archer /etc/gdm/Xsession[6315]: SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
    Jun 19 21:56:07 Archer /etc/gdm/Xsession[6315]: SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
    Jun 19 21:56:07 Archer /etc/gdm/Xsession[6315]: SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
    Jun 19 21:56:07 Archer /etc/gdm/Xsession[6315]: 21:56:07.157 [Connection worker] DEBUG o.g.t.i.provider.DefaultConnection - Tooling API provider 1.12 created.
    Jun 19 21:56:07 Archer /etc/gdm/Xsession[6315]: 21:56:07.386 [Connection worker] DEBUG o.g.t.i.provider.ProviderConnection - Configuring logging to level: INFO
    Jun 19 21:56:07 Archer /etc/gdm/Xsession[6315]: Tooling API is using target Gradle version: 1.12.
    Jun 19 21:56:07 Archer /etc/gdm/Xsession[6315]: Tooling API is using target Gradle version: 1.12.
    Jun 19 21:56:09 Archer /etc/gdm/Xsession[6315]: Could not determine classpath for class org.gradle.util.GradleVersion
    Jun 19 21:56:09 Archer /etc/gdm/Xsession[6315]: Could not determine classpath for class org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    Jun 19 21:56:09 Archer /etc/gdm/Xsession[6315]: Starting Gradle daemon
    Jun 19 21:56:09 Archer /etc/gdm/Xsession[6315]: Starting daemon process: workingDir = /home/kaleb/.gradle/daemon/1.12, daemonArgs: [/opt/java/bin/java, -XX:MaxPermSize=256m, -XX:+HeapDump
    Jun 19 21:56:09 Archer /etc/gdm/Xsession[6315]: Starting process 'Gradle build daemon'. Working directory: /home/kaleb/.gradle/daemon/1.12 Command: /opt/java/bin/java -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
    Jun 19 21:56:09 Archer /etc/gdm/Xsession[6315]: Successfully started process 'Gradle build daemon'
    Jun 19 21:37:15 Archer /etc/gdm/Xsession[6315]: at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:467)
    Jun 19 21:37:15 Archer /etc/gdm/Xsession[6315]: at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$4$2.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:546)
    Jun 19 21:37:15 Archer /etc/gdm/Xsession[6315]: at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$TaskRunnable.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:464)
    Jun 19 21:37:15 Archer /etc/gdm/Xsession[6315]: at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
    Jun 19 21:37:15 Archer /etc/gdm/Xsession[6315]: at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
    Jun 19 21:37:15 Archer /etc/gdm/Xsession[6315]: at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
    Jun 19 21:37:15 Archer /etc/gdm/Xsession[6315]: at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:171)
    Jun 19 21:37:15 Archer /etc/gdm/Xsession[6315]: at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$8.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:373)
    Jun 19 21:37:15 Archer /etc/gdm/Xsession[6315]: at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:419)
    Jun 19 21:37:15 Archer /etc/gdm/Xsession[6315]: at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    Jun 19 21:37:15 Archer /etc/gdm/Xsession[6315]: at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    Jun 19 21:37:15 Archer /etc/gdm/Xsession[6315]: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    Jun 19 21:37:15 Archer /etc/gdm/Xsession[6315]: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    Jun 19 21:37:15 Archer /etc/gdm/Xsession[6315]: at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Jun 19 21:37:15 Archer /etc/gdm/Xsession[6315]: at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:149)
    Jun 19 21:37:15 Archer /etc/gdm/Xsession[6315]: [ 244688]   WARN - .project.GradleProjectImporter -
    Jun 19 21:40:10 Archer /etc/gdm/Xsession[6315]: (nemo:6397): librsvg-WARNING **: CSS parsing error
    Jun 19 21:40:10 Archer /etc/gdm/Xsession[6315]: (nemo:6397): librsvg-WARNING **: CSS parsing error
    Jun 19 21:40:38 Archer /etc/gdm/Xsession[6315]: (nemo:6397): librsvg-WARNING **: CSS parsing error
    Jun 19 21:40:38 Archer /etc/gdm/Xsession[6315]: (nemo:6397): librsvg-WARNING **: CSS parsing error
    Jun 19 21:50:36 Archer gdm-Xorg-:0[495]: (II) intel(0): switch to mode 1920x1080@60.1 on eDP1 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
    Jun 19 21:50:40 Archer cinnamon-screensaver-dialog[7179]: pam_tally(cinnamon-screensaver:auth): Error opening /var/log/faillog for update
    Jun 19 21:50:40 Archer cinnamon-screensaver-dialog[7179]: pam_tally(cinnamon-screensaver:auth): Error opening /var/log/faillog for read
    Jun 19 21:50:44 Archer cinnamon-screensaver-dialog[7179]: pam_tally(cinnamon-screensaver:setcred): Error opening /var/log/faillog for update
    Jun 19 21:50:44 Archer cinnamon-screensaver-dialog[7179]: pam_tally(cinnamon-screensaver:setcred): Error opening /var/log/faillog for update
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:** I have no idea what happened, but I restarted like 6 times, made another android project to see if it would crash, and opened and closed Android Studio many times to try to break it again. Everything seems to be running okay now for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0):

Chack your Manifest target with your device updated vresions and try.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="?" />
<uses-sdk android:maxSdkVersion="?" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been scratching my head of Android studio bugs and crashes,, until I downloaded the beta version and created a fresh windows account seems to fix the problem,, my guess is various android studio versions cache something on the user account level which causes those crashes.
Hope that helps